# how can make a button goes to the next activity and passing its titleLabel in a string as well?

Tags: ios, swift

can anyone please guide me on how to make a button when its clicked goes to the next activity and pass its data to the next button

this is my code

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var electronics: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var pass:searchResultView = segue.destinationViewController as! searchResultView

    if(electronics.selected){
        pass.received = electronics.titleLabel!.text!
    }
}
```

when i run the app and click the button, it crashes!

here is the code in the searchResultView

```
class searchResultView: UIViewController {


    var received:String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

I tried to do re-write the code this way

```
@IBOutlet weak var electronics: UIButton!

@IBAction func electronics(sender: AnyObject) {
    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var pass:searchResultView = segue.destinationViewController as! searchResultView

            pass.received = electronics.titleLabel!.text!

    }


}
```

by implementing the code that passes the data inside the button itself

the app still crashes!

Comment: http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/

Comment: complete process is explained here http://peterwitham.com/swift/basics/pass-data-between-ios-views/

Comment: i saw this artical and tried to implement it in a string instead of label but i couldn't

Comment: @FattiKhan i want to pass the button titleLabel to the string not to label

Comment: electronics.titleLabel!.text! as you have used it its correct you  can use same as it is

Comment: why are you using segue as !searchResultView? it should be searchResultView instead

Comment: let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("searchResultView") as searchResultView
vc.received = electronics.titleLabel!.text!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController( vc , animated: false)

Comment: Try this code instead of segue and tell me whether this works or not

Comment: @FattiKhan can you please put it in an answer,

Comment: @FattiKhan i tried ur code, didn't work, still shows me an error, please put it in an answer,